# R: Use value from other data frame for matching columns values in a row

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I am working on a project for which I have written some R code. However, I ran into some troubles trying to improve the runtime.

There are two data frames that I use. It must be noted that matching observations can be found on random rows.

- df1 (called 'ac') contains historical demand actuals with columns "Region", "Product", "time" and "ac_qty".
- df2 (called 'fc') contains forecasts with columns "Region", "Product", "time" and "fc_qty".

I would like to create a third data frame (called 'er') that contains all the errors (er_qty) for each specific Region/Product/time combination. I have succeeded in this, using the following code:

```
# Examples of data frames 'ac' and 'fc':
ac <- data.frame("Region" = c("R1", "R2", "R3"), 
             "Product" = c("P1", "P2", "P3"), 
             "time" = c(1, 2, 2), 
             "ac_qty" = c(4, 2, 3) )

fc <- data.frame("Region" = c("R2", "R1", "R3"), 
             "Product" = c("P2", "P1", "P3"), 
             "time" = c(2, 1, 2), 
             "fc_qty" = c(2, 1, 3) )

# Copy data frame with forecasts, and expand (separated data frames for later processing)
er <- fc

# Finding corresponding ac_qty for fc_qty with given Region/Product/time:
for (i in 1:length(er$fc_qty)) {
    er$ac_qty[i] <- ac$ac_qty[ac$Region == er$Region[i] & ac$Product== er$Product[i] & ac$time == er$time[i] ]
}

er$er_qty <- er$fc_qty- er$ac_qty
```

Because the for-loop need to iterate over 200,000 rows in the data frame, it takes a lot of time to compute all values. I need to substantially decrease the run time of the script. I tried using a with() function, but that resulted in wrong values after verifivation.

```
er$ac_qty<- with(ac, ac_qty[which(Region == er$Region & Product == er$Product & time == er$time)])
```

Furthermore, the code above gave me this warning: "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

What would be the best way to find the values of demand quantities (ac_qty) that match to a forecast (fc_qty) that has the same variable for the Region, Product and time columns?

Thank you.

Comment: Please make a small reproducible example and what the output should look like.

Comment: I have provided it now in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using left_join (import dplyr package),

here we're joining two data frames based on their common columns

```
er <- left_join(ac, fc, by = c("Region", "Product", "time") )

er <- mutate(er, er_qty = fc_qty - ac_qty) %>% select(-fc_qty,-ac_qty)
```

On the Second line, we're creating a new column using mutate, then using select removing fc_qty, ac_qty (select is optional)

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you very much! This indeed helped and results in the correct values for all rows.